# Is this expression with the Levi-Civita tensor correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was doing a calculation about Nuclear Physics and in one step of the calculation I obtained
$$
\varepsilon_{kbc} n_k n_b \tau_c
$$
where $\tau_c$ is $2\times2$ Pauli matrix and $n_k$ is the k-component of a normalized vector (i.e. $n_a n_a =1$). To obtain the correct result is needed that
$$
\varepsilon_{kbc} n_k n_b \tau_c = 0
$$
However, I am not totally sure if this is always correct. ¿Is there some property of Levi-Civita tensor associated with it?

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Levi-Civita symbol is antisymettric about swapping one index with another i.e. $\epsilon_{ijk} = -\epsilon_{jik}$ so

$\epsilon_{kbc}n_kn_b \tau_c = - \epsilon_{bkc}n_kn_b \tau_c$

but also we can swap the dummy indices $k$ and $b$:

$\epsilon_{kbc}n_kn_b \tau_c = \epsilon_{bkc}n_bn_k \tau_c $

hence

$- \epsilon_{bkc}n_kn_b \tau_c = \epsilon_{bkc}n_bn_k \tau_c = \epsilon_{bkc}n_kn_b \tau_c\\
\implies \epsilon_{kbc}n_kn_b \tau_c = 0 $

(so yes, the expression is always true)